# Issue running emscripten after installing/configuring from emsdk

Tags: emscripten

> **Note:** I have already added a comment onto [emscripten github issue #5215](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/5215), but have yet to receive a response there.

I am having issues trying to use emcc when running a version of emscripten that I installed and configured using `emsdk-portable.tar.gz`.  I followed the instructions here:

http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#platform-notes-installation-instructions-sdk

I used these commands in the root folder that I unpacked to as instructed:

```
./emsdk update
./emsdk install latest
./emsdk activate latest
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

Once I'd done this, the file `/home/pete/.emscripten` looked like this:

```
import os
LLVM_ROOT='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit'
EMSCRIPTEN_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/optimizer'
BINARYEN_ROOT='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/binaryen'
NODE_JS='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/node/4.1.1_64bit/bin/node'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.22'
SPIDERMONKEY_ENGINE = ''
V8_ENGINE = ''
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
```

When checking the version of ./emcc, I got this output:

```
pete@PetesUbu:~/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.22$ ./emcc -v
INFO:root:generating system asset: is_vanilla.txt... (this will be cached in "/home/pete/.emscripten_cache/is_vanilla.txt" for subsequent builds)
/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/llc: relocation error: /home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/llc: symbol _ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
INFO:root: - ok
WARNING:root:(Emscripten: unknown: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects, clearing cache)
CRITICAL:root:Could not verify LLVM version: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/llc: relocation error: /home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/llc: symbol _ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
CRITICAL:root:fastcomp in use, but LLVM has not been built with the JavaScript backend as a target, llc reports:
===========================================================================
(no targets could be identified: need more than 1 value to unpack)
===========================================================================
CRITICAL:root:you can fall back to the older (pre-fastcomp) compiler core, although that is not recommended, see http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/LLVM-Backend.html
INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
CRITICAL:root:failing sanity checks due to previous fastcomp failure
```

The first warning looks to be python related, and I noticed python wasn't set up in the environment variables... so I added it to ./emscripten to look like this:

```
import os
LLVM_ROOT='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit'
EMSCRIPTEN_NATIVE_OPTIMIZER='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/optimizer'
BINARYEN_ROOT='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/binaryen'
NODE_JS='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/node/4.1.1_64bit/bin/node'
EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT='/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.22'
SPIDERMONKEY_ENGINE = ''
V8_ENGINE = ''
TEMP_DIR = '/tmp'
COMPILER_ENGINE = NODE_JS
JS_ENGINES = [NODE_JS]
PYTHON = 'python'
```

'python' calls a version of python 2.7.x that is above the minimum suggested in the instructions... I can't remember which off the top of my head, but I checked.

And so I called the version of ./emcc again, to get this output:

```
pete@PetesUbu:~/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.22$ ./emcc -v
WARNING:root:(Emscripten: settings file has changed, clearing cache)
CRITICAL:root:Could not verify LLVM version: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
/home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/llc: relocation error: /home/pete/Programming/Emscripten/emsdk-portable/clang/e1.37.22_64bit/llc: symbol _ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
CRITICAL:root:fastcomp in use, but LLVM has not been built with the JavaScript backend as a target, llc reports:
===========================================================================
(no targets could be identified: need more than 1 value to unpack)
===========================================================================
CRITICAL:root:you can fall back to the older (pre-fastcomp) compiler core, although that is not recommended, see http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/LLVM-Backend.html
INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
CRITICAL:root:failing sanity checks due to previous fastcomp failure
```

It looks as if I fixed the python issue, but I'm not sure what my next move is from here. Anyone have any ideas what I should try or look at next?

Comment: Are you talking about travis ci? Is that involved here?

Comment: I see you are because you added it as a tag to my question... Forgive me if I've missed something, but there is no mention of travis-ci in my question

Comment: Sorry, got it mixed up in my mind somehow as I was reading other GitHub issues related to travis/emscripten (!)  But...er... if you happen to be having these problems on a Linux host somewhere, a clang host on Mac doesn't seem to have them.  If that helps anyone (e.g. someone trying this on a Travis Linux VM, which is where I saw/researched the problem)

Comment: That's fair play. I'm currently just building it straight up on my linux machine

Comment: Strange as it was only on Travis (and only on their Linux image), I and others running on recent distros had no problems.  Be sure in your queries to list off all your version info, because no one building emscripten (in our little sub-culture) has had problems, just that Travis build, which has the exact errors you cite.

Comment: Fair play. It was ages now since I did this, I'll have to try it again soon and report back